# How can i change line in vsc for the same line of code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code how can my code change line when it goes to the end of the visible space? Instead of keep going to the right and forces me to use scroll bar?

Comment: **View** > **Word Wrap**

Comment: @rioV8 I don't think that's what they talking about. It sounds like they're saying the editor viewport doesn't scroll to keep the caret within view whenever they type anything like adding/removing characters or moving the caret with arrow keys (which it should). Don, did I understand you right? If I did, this sounds like a bug. A gif of it happening could be useful just to prove that it's happening.